# how to run .NET MAUI on windows without visual studio?

Tags: .net, windows, maui

Is it possible to run the .net Maui project on windows in the command prompt? I tried simple "dotnet run"
but it said:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Tooling.targets(69,5): error
> XA5300: The Android SDK directory could not be found. Check that the Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio shows a vali
> d installation. To use a custom SDK path for a command line build, set the 'AndroidSdkDirectory' MSBuild property to th
> e custom path. [C:\Users\Windows\Documents\csharp-scripts\MauiTest1\MauiTest1.csproj]

I don't want to test the app on android but on windows

Comment: are you trying to build the windows project?  Or run a project that has already been built?

Comment: I'm trying to run already built project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows, the best way I found out to compile and run the app is by doing it in 3 steps:

1. Compile with `msbuild`
2. Install the app using Add-AppxPackage
3. Run the package

I've written the following script for `pwsh` 7:

```
# Locate msbuild
$msbuild = "$((gci -Path (gci "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio\2*" )[-1])[-1].FullName)\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"
new-alias msbuild $msbuild -Force

# Find sln
$sln = gci *.sln -Recurse -Depth 3 | Select -First 1
$baseDir = (gci -Path $sln.Directory *.csproj -Depth 1 | select -First 1).Directory

# 1. Build
msbuild $sln -r -p:Configuration=Debug -p:RestorePackages=false -p:TargetFramework=net6.0-windows10.0.19041

# 2. Find AppxManifest and Install it
$appManifest = Get-ChildItem -Path "$baseDir/bin" AppxManifest.xml -Depth 3 | Select-Object -First 1
import-module appx -usewindowspowershell
Add-AppxPackage $appManifest.FullName -Register

# 3. Get app guid to launch it
$guid = (gci *.csproj -Path $sln.Directory -Depth 1 | gc | Select-String -Pattern 'Guid>([^<]*)<').Matches.Groups[1].Value
$app = Get-AppxPackage -Name $guid;
explorer "shell:appsFolder\$($app.PackageFamilyName)!App"
```

## Edit

If you want to include resources such as Images and Fonts they won't be automatically copied, so:

```
# Copy raw assets
gci "$baseDir/Resources/Raw" | cp -Destination $appManifest.Directory

# Copy built assets
gci -Path "$baseDir/obj" -Include resizetizer -Depth 3 | 
    gci -Exclude m | gci -Recurse -File | cp -Destination $appManifest.Directory
```

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, I used the following steps for using .NET MAUI on Windows without Visual Studio, and it works fine.

Step1. Install .NET SDK in https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download .

Step2. Install .NET MAUI workload with the dotnet CLI. Launch a command prompt and enter the following:

```
dotnet workload install maui
```

Step3. Verify and install missing components with maui-check command line utility.

```
dotnet tool install -g redth.net.MAUI.check
maui-check
```

Step4. Create a new folder and a new MAUI app.

Step5. Start your Android Emulator.

Step6. Run the MAUI app in the Android Simulator.

```
dotnet build -t:Run -f net6.0-android
```

According to the [Build Windows target using dotnet build instead of msbuild.exe](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3926), it seems like using dotnet way to to build a .NET MAUI app for Windows doesn't work with the.NET MAUI.

Comment: I managed to build the app for windows using `dotnet build -f net6.0-windows` (if I remember correctly). Currently I'm trying to run the build on windows.

Comment: Hi, May I ask which step you are facing now?